# Реализация мгновенных сообщенй.

Tags: html, javascript, php, mysql

На сайте реализую мгновенные сообщения (cайт на php) отправку сообщений реализовал. Начал пробовать реализовывать обновление списка сообщений и зашёл в тупик. Пытаюсь реализовать через [SSE](http://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events) понял как подключатся к серверу но он на php и ... Вообщем я совсем запутался и нужна помощь расставить всё по местам.
В теории sse подключается к серверу а тот в свою очередь подключается к таблице mysql и как только в таблице появляется новая строчка сервер пишет data: тут что нибудь\n\n  но у меня не получается соединится с php файлом т.к. он выполняется непосредственно на сервере и я не знаю что мне делать. И второе, даже если удастся каким то образом подключится к серверу то к mysql то подключится нельзя, можно только отправлять запросы!
Как реализовать обновление списка сообщений ?

Comment: в чем именно проблема ? как я понимаю SSE реализует систему типа long-pool, ваш клиент делает запрос к серверу, начинает получать данные, сервер при получении запроса присоединяется к mysql и время от времени делает запросы, ответы от mysql выкиывабтся в виде строчек 

data: reply\n\n

javascript их выводит, все рады. В чем проблема ?

ps: для IM я бы использовал websockets к jabber(XMPP) серверу или чему нить подобному и не мучался.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/191302/php-server-sent-events-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82 Почему сообщения не выводились я разобрался но когда никакого long-pool не выходит sse выводит сообщения после того как файл сервер php отработает, а поидеи должен выводить во время.

Comment: сделайте flush() после echo, [почитайте здесь](http://muzso.hu/2008/02/19/php-output-buffering)

Answer (score 1):

Уже давал ссылку в комментарии к вопросу с таким же названием. На w3school. Теперь по слогам:

Файл .html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
  {
  var source=new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
    };
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

demo_sse.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Взято отсюда: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

Comment: Спасибо большое но проблема не в этом, подключится к серверу у меня получилась и давно но сервер на php работает непосредственно на самом сервере и выдаёт данные по окончанию работы скрипта - то есть если я подключусь к серверу в котором будет цикл через каждую секунду выдавать сообщение и так предположим 10 раз то у клиента вместо того чтобы появлялись 10 раз через 1 секунду выдавать сообщение у него через 10 секунд появится сразу 10 сообщений.

Comment: То есть вот именно этот текст не выдаёт сообщения через 1с?

Ваши страницы не доступны из интернета? А то можно было бы протестировать...

Comment: попробуйте вот это код сервера php и вы поймёте суть проблемы:
 header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
 $x = 0;
 $y = 10;
 while ($x<10){
  $x++; // Увеличение счетчика
  echo "data: $x \n\n";
  $y++;
  sleep(1);
 }
этот код выводить по одному сообщений каждую секунду 10 раз

но у клиента будут выводится 10 собщений каждые 10 секунд

Comment: Смотрите комментарий @eicto к вопросу. Вероятно причина в отсутствии flush и буферизации сообщений. Но неясно, почему Вы не желаете проверить работающий вариант, а уже затем искать у себя ошибку.